# Recovering data from parts of partition which were not overwritten

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

I was running Xubuntu in a VMware virtual machine, with a 40GB virtual hard drive.  I accidentally overwrote the first 8GB with a Raspberry Pi image.  I would like to recover files (text files, images, PDFs) from the remaining 32GB.

I tried [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), but it only recovered files from the first 8GB.

Any suggestions?